# Angular: Send Checkbox Form Data to Firebase

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, firebase

I have a object called `list` in my JS file:

```
$scope.list = {
  hospital : 'Hospital',
  clinic : 'Clinic',
  gp : 'GP',
  denist : 'Dentist',
  aae : 'A&E'
};
```

I'm printing these five facilities to the form like so:

```
<form role="form" name="addPlaceForm" ng-submit="createHospital(newHospital)">
   <label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="(key, value) in list">
       <input type="checkbox" id="{{ key }}" value="{{ key }}" ng-model="newHospital.facilities">{{ value }}
   </label>
</form>
```

When I submit my form, I'd like it to send the the result of the checked checkboxes to my `facilities` object in Firebase. My `createHospital` function looks like this:

```
var rootRef = new Firebase('URL');
var placesRef = rootRef.child('places');

function createHospital(hospital) {
  placesRef.push(hospital);
}
```

How can I push only the checked checkboxes to an nested object called `facilities` which sits inside my `places` object that's currently in my Firebase?

Any help with this is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I made a plunker to demonstrate how to do this at http://plnkr.co/kfH4I5Fzy2Ma14FjQj67.

You were mostly right. The changes I made was making the ng-model="newHospital.facilities[key]" and initializing $scope.newHospital to {} so it is seen in the controller. I also added a submit button.

```
<form role="form" name="addPlaceForm" ng-submit="createHospital(newHospital)">
   <label class="checkbox-inline" ng-repeat="(key, value) in list">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ key }}" value="{{ key }}" ng-model="newHospital.facilities[key]">{{ value }}
   </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there a way for that `$scope.newHospital` to sit inside the `createHospital()` function?

Comment: I can't think of any way. We need the newHospital object to be on the scope so we can pass it into the createHospital function. What are you trying to do?